# How can a radio button get checked by filling in a text field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a HTML form, with radio buttons and a text field for some of them. When filling in a textfield, I want the corresponding radio button to be checked.

I suppose it's possible with Javascript. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it without jquery. This will also uncheck the radio button if the input is blank.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var input = inputs[i];
  input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    if (this.value == "") {
      this.nextElementSibling.checked = false;
    } else {
      this.nextElementSibling.checked = true;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="radio">
<input type="text">
<input type="radio">
```

If you have the radio buttons before the text fields, just change `nextElementSibling` to `previousElementSibling`.

**Explanation**

`document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')` will return an array of DOM elements that represent each of your input text fields.

Then, a `for` loop is used to loop through each text field.

For each text field, an event listener is added that will call the function that is defined whenever the user changes the `input` in the text field. Don't use on `change` here, because that would only trigger the event when focus leaves the text field (in other words, when the user clicks outside the text field).

In the event listener, we can reference the current text field with `this`.

We can get a reference to the radio button that is next to the current text field using `this.nextElementSibling`. Attempting to use `this.nextSibling` will not work, as it will find a node that contains the actual text in your input field.

The `if` statement checks if the current text field is blank. If it is blank it will set the `checked` attribute of the corresponding radio button to `false`, but if it is not blank, it will set `checked` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you have jquery on the page but with jQuery you could use

```
$('#idOfTextbox').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    $('#idOfCheckbox').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.on('input' ...`

Please check out the snippet.

```js
$('.container').on('input' , 'input[type=text]',function(e){
  var that = $(this);
  that.prev().prop({'checked':that.val().length>0});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=container>
<div><input type=radio /><input type=text></div>
<div><input type=radio /><input type=text></div>
<div><input type=radio /><input type=text></div>
<div><input type=radio /><input type=text></div>
<div><input type=radio /><input type=text></div>
</div>
```